# How to run camera only in portrait mode

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I want to run camera "only in portrait mode". I set screenOrientation as portrait in AndroidManifest however it still change the orientation to landscape while capturing the photo. How do I force it to run on only portrait mode. (causes only samsung galaxy s3 and note 2)

Answer (score 0):

Try put this in the OnCreate of your Activity

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

solution came with a simple modification in androidmanifest. add configChanges attribute to activity properties.

```
<activity android:name="com.x.yactivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

that's all.